# XSLT multiple repeatable child nodes

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working with a set of records that have multiple different child node types that are repeatable. The end goal is to create a CSV mapping, and because of the nesting, each XML record can map to many CSV line items.

I understand how to use `for-each` to create multiple output lines, but I am having trouble because there are two different cases to loop over.

In the following example, `App` is the base record, `SST_Interval` is repeatable (1 or more), and `ReplacementPart` can have 0 or more `PartType`s.

I would like to extract a CSV that has the following format

`app_id|base_vehicle_id|sst_interval_id|sst_interval_month|part_type_id`

For the record shown below, the result would look like this

```
915152|18287|646|12|10007
915152|18287|646|12|12277
915152|18287|646|12|18159
915152|18287|32523|24|10007
915152|18287|32523|24|12277
915152|18287|32523646|24|18159
```

Here is the record

```
<App action="A" id="915152" ref="568874">
    <BaseVehicle id="18287" />
    <EngineVIN id="25" />
    <Note id="8722" vehicleattribute="no" />
    <Position id="1" />
    <MOTOR_Operation id="551841">
        <SkillCode>G</SkillCode>
        <Base_MOTOR_EWT minutes="1" />
        <SST_Interval id="646">
            <SST_IndicatorImage><![CDATA[sstgm140001]]></SST_IndicatorImage>
            <SST_IndicatorText><![CDATA[Change Engine Oil Soon]]></SST_IndicatorText>
            <SST_Frequency id="7" />
            <SST_IntervalMonth><![CDATA[12]]></SST_IntervalMonth>
            <SST_SevereService id="2080" />
            <SST_Note1 id="5117" />
        </SST_Interval>
        <SST_Interval id="32523">
            <SST_IndicatorImage><![CDATA[sstgm140001]]></SST_IndicatorImage>
            <SST_IndicatorText><![CDATA[Change Engine Oil Soon]]></SST_IndicatorText>
            <SST_Frequency id="7" />
            <SST_IntervalMonth><![CDATA[24]]></SST_IntervalMonth>
            <SST_SevereService id="2080" />
            <SST_Note1 id="5117" />
        </SST_Interval>
        <ReplacementPart>
            <PartType id="10007" servicetype_id="1" />
            <PartType id="12277" servicetype_id="1" />
            <PartType id="18159" servicetype_id="1" />
        </ReplacementPart>
    </MOTOR_Operation>
</App>
```

Here is the XSLT I have tried. If you can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="Header|Footer">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="App">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MOTOR_Operation/SST_Interval"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PartType">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="csv"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SST_Interval">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::App/@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="csv-nl"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::App/MOTOR_Operation/ReplacementPart/PartType">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$tmp"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="csv">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '|')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="csv-nl">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xa;')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the expected result if there are 0  `PartType`s?

Comment: The last field, `part_type_id` would be empty like so: `915152|18287|646|12||`

Comment: But how many rows should there be? You have exactly one row for each existing `PartType`, so if none exist, logically there should be 0 rows.

Comment: You have a good point. Fully normalized, there should be two separate tables, one for services and one for service-part mappings. If that were the case, there would be no entry for the service-part table if there are no parts. As a first pass, I'm converting the XML to a more denormalized form, so I would like to a row saying this service exists and it has no parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are far off. You just need to change the definition of the `tmp` variable to include more fields, and use mode `csv` for all of them, and then change the template matching `PartType` to use `csv-nl` instead.

Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Header|Footer">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="App">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MOTOR_Operation/SST_Interval"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PartType">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="csv-nl"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SST_Interval">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::App/@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::App/BaseVehicle/@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SST_IntervalMonth" mode="csv"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::App/MOTOR_Operation/ReplacementPart/PartType">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$tmp"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="csv">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '|')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="csv-nl">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xa;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, if you wanted to cope with missing nodes, I would perhaps disregard the templates with mode, and store the separator and new line characters in variables instead. Then you could do this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="sep" select="'|'" />
  <xsl:variable name="nl" select="'&#xa;'" />

  <xsl:template match="App">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MOTOR_Operation/SST_Interval"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PartType">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SST_Interval">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::App/@id" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::App/BaseVehicle/@id" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
      <xsl:value-of select="SST_IntervalMonth"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$sep" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::App/MOTOR_Operation/ReplacementPart/PartType">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$tmp"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT 2: In the case of there being no `PartType` records, try replacing the current `xsl:for-each` with this code

```
    <xsl:variable name="PartTypes" select="ancestor::App/MOTOR_Operation/ReplacementPart/PartType" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$PartTypes">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$tmp"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="not($PartTypes)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$tmp"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Him Tim, you are exactly right ... but embarrassingly I realized this is not the actual problem i am experiencing. Is there a way to add a choose/when to my csv templates to account for missing nodes? Otherwise I will get CSV rows with fewer values than the other rows

Comment: I've shown an alternate solution in my answer, if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Much appreciated, Tim. I guess sometime's the simpler, less elegant solution is the best one. I think the `for-each` on PartType is problematic because then nothing gets printed when there are no PartTypes in the record (it can have 0 or more). I'll try to get rid of the `for-each`

Comment: I've made a second edit to my question to show how this could be handled

Comment: PERFECT! I owe you a beer

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT you presented in the question works exactly as it should.  The main problem is simply that you use mode `csv-nl` in the wrong place.  Additionally, there's nothing to provide the base vehicle ID and interval month fields, but it looks pretty straightforward to add those.

---

**Update:**
With respect to optional fields, although you *could* use XSL's conditional constructs, a more natural approach would be to simply allow the transformation of the relevant field to produce nothing.  The only trick here is that for your application you must always output a delimiter, but that arises from your particular approach to inserting delimiters.

One fairly clean way to work within that framework would be to unconditionally *call* a named template that transforms the optional element and adds the delimiter.  I have updated the stylesheet below to demonstrate this for the base vehicle id.

---

Allow me, however, to suggest some simplifications:

- You don't need to `omit-xml-declarations` when the output method is text
- you don't need to `strip-space` from the input elements because you're not actually using any text nodes; only attribute nodes are contributing to the output.  Note also that whitespace stripping applies exclusively to *whitespace-only* text nodes
- You don't need to suppress `<Header>` and `<Footer>` elements when there aren't any in the input, OR when the structure of the stylesheet and input result in such nodes never being transformed in the first place.
- You're a bit verbose in providing a template for `PartType` when you know at the point where you select it for transformation that you want only its `id` attribute
- Leveraging template parameters could make you code cleaner
- Prefer to avoid `xsl:for-each` where you don't need it.  Often, you can simply `xsl:apply-templates` to the same nodes, instead
- As a personal style choice, I prefer to avoid the `concat()` function where I can instead simply provide a sequence of `xsl:value-of` and / or `xsl:text` elements

Taking all those into account, I'd suggest this variation on your stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="App">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MOTOR_Operation/SST_Interval"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SST_Interval">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::App/@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="optional-vehicle"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" mode="csv"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SST_IntervalMonth" mode="csv"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../ReplacementPart/PartType/@id" mode="csv-nl">
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$tmp"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="optional-vehicle">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::App/BaseVehicle/@id"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="csv">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="csv-nl">
    <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a great solution! If `BaseVehicle` is optional, is there a way to edit the csv/csv-nl templates so that I can output the delimiter if the `BaseVehicle` is not present in the `App` record?

Comment: Ok, @emrosenf, I've updated the answer to address optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="App">
    <xsl:variable name="common1">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BaseVehicle/@id"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="MOTOR_Operation/SST_Interval">
        <xsl:variable name="common2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$common1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="SST_IntervalMonth"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="part-types" select="../ReplacementPart/PartType" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$part-types">
            <xsl:value-of select="$common2"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not($part-types)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$common2"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The problem with `for-each` is that ReplacementPart/PartType is optional, so it fails when the count is 0

Comment: Well, as I said in the comment to your question, this makes very little sense to me. But I did add a row for each `SST_Interval`, with an empty cell at the end, for the case of 0 `PartType`s.